# Is it okay to ask about modern feelings toward historic events?

Tags: discussion

For instance, would it be okay for a user to ask "How is the execution of Charles I in 1649 viewed in modern day Britain?" This seems like a subjective question and not every Briton will have the same view on the topic, but I can understand where the question is coming from. The user may wish to know, for instance, whether the execution is viewed as a 'stain' on British history or a celebrated overthrow of a treasonous monarch.

Comment: The vast majority of such questions will be subjective.  Even if there is public opinion polling available, opinion polls are subtle tools and require interpretation and crafting.  Would such questions help us to understand or practice history? And I suspect the answer to such questions has more to do with politics than history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, and I think Mark's comment is right. Any question along the lines you proposed would invite lots of subjective answers. Your instincts are right that this question would be subjective. I think if a question could be worded in such a way that a valid answer would convey a historical viewpoint for a society, or prevailing viewpoint, that might work.